# how to concatenate input to function

Tags: python

i have some setter function :

```
      @images_path.setter
      def images_path(self, *images_path: tuple):
         self.__images_path = 
           os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.pardir,'BossGame', 'Resources','images'))
```

i want to pass input that contain: 'BossGame', 'Resources', 'images'
in the input images_path to the os.path.join function

```
 class Nature(object):

   def __init__(self):

    self.images_path = ['BossGame', 'Resources', 'images']
    self.sound_path = ['BossGame', 'Resources', 'music']

    pass

   @property
   def images_path(self)->str:
       return self.__images_path

   @images_path.setter
   def images_path(self, *images_path: tuple):
       self.__images_path = 
           os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.pardir,images_path))
```

the Error:

```
      TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def images_path(self, path_seq):
   self.__images_path = 
       os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.pardir, *path_seq))
```

Please note that you have used `images_path` both as variable name and function name. This is really bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
self.__images_path = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.pardir,pth)) for pth in images_path]
```

By default, the function doesn't accept a list so you can't force one to it, but you may loop over the list and run the function n times, where n is the size of the list